# Compute checksums for a random selection of files whose names are listed in a file

Tags: linux, checksum

Let's say I have a file named `list_of_files.txt` where each line corresponds to a file on the disk. For example:

```
dir1/fileA.ext1
dir1/subdir1/fileB.ext2
fileC.ext3
dir2/fileD.ext4
fileE.ext5
```

I want to randomly select a number of files from that list and compute `cksum` or `md5sum` for them.

I know that I can randomly select say 3 files with `shuf -n 3 list_of_files.txt`, but how do I make `cksum` treat them as file names instead of text content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If paths in the file are newline-terminated and provided as-is, i.e. if each line is a separate verbatim path, then a shell loop will do:

```
shuf -n 3 list_of_files.txt | while IFS= read -r pth; do
   cksum "$pth"
done
```

There is also `xargs` (see the [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html) and more advanced [GNU `xargs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/xargs-options.html)), there is [GNU `parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html) (note [non-GNU `parallel` exists](https://linux.die.net/man/1/parallel) and I'm not referring to it). With the right tool and proper options you can make one `cksum` process more than one path (spawning less `cksum` processes is beneficial in general) or run two or more `cksum` processes in parallel.

To process as few as three files, I may stick to our shell loop because of portability; unless the files are big and I expect three `cksum` processes running in parallel to be substantially faster than one `cksum` at a time. I'm not an expert in GNU `parallel`, but it seems a solution is as simple as:

```
 shuf -n 3 list_of_files.txt | parallel cksum
```

By default GNU `parallel` limits the number of simultaneous jobs by the number of CPU cores. Three or more cores are common nowadays, so the command will probably run three `cksum` processes in parallel. Formally this is not portable though. Also note that processing three files in parallel means reading three files in parallel. I/O may be a bottleneck and this may reduce the benefit of parallel jobs or even make things worse.

Even then `parallel` may be useful. Use `-j 1` to limit the number of jobs to 1:

```
 shuf -n 3 list_of_files.txt | parallel -j 1 cksum
```

The files will be processed sequentially like in our shell loop, but the syntax is simpler. In case of our shell loop you need to know you want [`IFS= read -r pth`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123/108618), not just `read pth`; and you need to know you (in many shells) want [`cksum "$pth"`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618), not `cksum $pth`. The solution with GNU `parallel` is less error-prone. [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Note `xargs` by default interprets quotes and backslashes, and it considers spaces as delimiters. This means `shuf -n 3 list_of_files.txt | xargs cksum` is probably not what you want. Your example will work, but in general you need additional quotes and/or backslashes in the file; xor you need `xargs -d '\n'` where `-d` is a non-portable option of GNU `xargs`. My assumption was "paths in the file are newline-terminated and provided as-is". With this assumption GNU `parallel` works out of the box (i.e. without additional options), xargs doesn't. With GNU `xargs` you can do this:

```
shuf -n 3 list_of_files.txt | xargs -d '\n' cksum
```

If you can use GNU `xargs` (to save the day with `-d '\n'`) then probably you can use GNU `parallel`. If you forget `-j 1` when using GNU `parallel`, the command may perform worse but it will still work. If you forget `-d '\n'` when using GNU `xargs` and the pathnames are provided as-is, then it's a bug. That's why I recommended GNU `parallel` first.

GNU parallel is capable of processing null-terminated strings (the option is `-0`), so is GNU `xargs` (`-0` instead of `-d '\n'`) and GNU `shuf` (with `-z`). Your input file uses newline-terminated lines, but if you ever need to work with pathnames that (may) contain newline characters then changing the terminator in the file and adding the proper options is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks! `xargs` works well for my purpose. I don't have that many files and `xargs` works with `md5sum`

Comment: @C.J.Jackson OK, but note sole `xargs` interprets quotes and backslashes, and it considers spaces as delimiters. Your example will work, but in general you need additional quotes and/or backslashes; xor you need `xargs -d '\n'` (non-portable option of GNU `xargs`). My assumption was "paths in the file are newline-terminated and provided as-is". With this assumption GNU `parallel` works out of the box (i.e. without additional options), `xargs` doesn't. If you can use GNU `xargs` (to save the day with `-d '\n'`) then *probably* you can use GNU `parallel`. That's why I recommended GNU `parallel`.